# Bode plot of gain and phase

Tags: ltspice

I try to do a simulation on LTspice (simulation of the PA107DP amplifier from apex microtechnology) and during my simulation I noticed that I have a phase shift. so i want to see my bode diagram but i cant get it how could i do in this case?
[image]

and how I can choose its parameters. I have to base on what to fill them and to have my bode diagram [image]

Comment: What is "depahsage"?

Comment: The phase shift

Comment: Where is your ac signal source? I can see only a sin source for TRAN simulations.

Comment: You need to replace V1 by an AC source in order to run an AC simulation.

Comment: how can I replace it? I put the "voltage" after I change the parameters, I put 'SINE'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was mentioned in your question's comments, you need to specify an AC source to do an `.ac` small signal analysis and get your Bode plots.  You don't need to replace V1, but simply need to modify the parameters in this section.  For your case, it sounds like you want 1 for amplitude and 10 for phase:

[image]

---

I would also change your `.ac` analysis settings to get better resolution and so you can see what your feedback capacitor is doing at higher frequencies, for example:

[image]

---

Finally, this is what I get using the above settings to run your simulation.

[image]

Comment: thank you very much, I need to  increase the bandwidth  but without changing the value of the capacity C1 (that I set it to 10e-12). how could i do?

Comment: @ChàiMà Now this is a "how to use opamps" question.  Only quick thing I can mention is reducing R3 and R1 values.  Otherwise, I suggest accepting this answer since it obviously solved your initial problem, and then go create a new question on opamp poles/zeros due to the feedback network.